# ui-router $state.go fails to make transition in jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I have a working SPA in AngularJS that I want to test for state transition in ui-router.

This is my application configuration:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'dialogs.main', 'ngSanitize']);

myapp.provider('AuthRule', function () {
    return {
        $get: function () {
            return new AuthRules();
        },
        Rules: new AuthRules()
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function AuthRules() 
    { 
        /////variables defition
    }
}
myapp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', 'AuthRuleProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, AuthRuleProvider) {

            var AuthRule = AuthRuleProvider.Rules;
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider
                .state("admin", {
                    url: "/admin",
                    templateUrl: "Views/admin/index.html",
                    controller: "AdminController",
                    auth: AuthRule.Admin
                })
                .state("admin.orders", {
                    url: "/orders",
                    templateUrl: "Views/admin/orders/index.html",
                    controller: "admin.OrdersController",
                    auth: AuthRule.Admin
                })
                .state("root.unauthorized", {
                    url: "unauthorized",
                    templateUrl: "Views/layout/unauthorized.html"
                })
                .state("root", {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: "Views/content.html",
                    controller: "AppController",
                    auth: AuthRule.Root
                });
        }
]).run(function ($rootScope, $location, UserAuth, orderService, $state, AuthRule) {


    UserAuth.authorize(AuthRule.Import.roles).then(function () {
        $rootScope.user = UserAuth.getUser();
    }, function () {
        $rootScope.user = UserAuth.getUser();
    });


    var bypassRoute;

    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams) {
        if (bypassRoute) {
            bypassRoute = false;
            return;
        }

        var requireLogin =  typeof toState.auth != 'undefined' &&
                            typeof toState.auth.requireLogin != 'undefined ' &&
                            toState.auth.requireLogin;

        if (requireLogin) {
            bypassRoute = true;
            event.preventDefault();

            var roles = typeof toState.auth != 'undefined' &&
                        typeof toState.auth.roles != 'undefined' &&
                        toState.auth.roles;

            UserAuth.authorize(roles).then(
                function () {
                    $state.go(toState, toParams);
                },
                function () {
                    $state.go("root.unauthorized");
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Jasmine test:

```
describe('State', function () {
    var $rootScope, $state, $injector;

    var $httpBackend, $rootScope, $q;
    var userMock = { Name: 'Mr. User', Roles: ['Role1', 'Role2'] };


    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, _UserAuth_, _$httpBackend_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $state = _$state_;
            $injector = _$injector_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        }));

    beforeEach(
        inject(function ($templateCache, $httpBackend) {
            $templateCache.put('Views/admin/index.html', '');
            $templateCache.put('Views/layout/unauthorized.html', '');
            $httpBackend.when('GET', 'api/users').respond(userMock);
        }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('root should be configured correctly', function () {
        var state = 'root';
        $state.go(state);
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);
    });

    it('root.undefined should be configured correctly', function () {
        var state = 'root.unauthorized';
        $state.go(state);
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);
    });

    it('admin should be configured correctly', function () {
        var state = 'admin';
        $state.go(state);
        $httpBackend.flush();
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);
    });  
});
```

Transition to 'root.undefined' works ok but the `admin should be configured correctly` test fails with the following text:

```
Result Message: Expected 'root' to be 'admin'.
```

So the $state.go call gets redirected to '/', probably because of a missing dependency or something but I cannot figure it out and I cannot debug the test because it is written in Visual Studio and ran with Chutzpah.